# How to render partial form as a horizontal form in rails 4

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, form-for

I have a partial (triggered by ajax) on my main page which consists of a form. I would like the form to be displayed horizontally rather than vertically.  I have tried everything such as wrapping in `<form class="form-inline">` I've tried `<%=f.number_field :pointsSpend, :class => "checkbox inline"%>` and then altering the css to `display: inline` but none of it seems to work

The main form in which the partial is rendered:

```
 <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <%= link_to image_tag("biceps.jpg"),'#', id: 'ChallengeButton', class: "btn btn-lg btn-primary" %>
            <div id="challengeCentre"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

The form

```
<%= form_for(@challenge) do |f| %>

  <% if @challenge.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@challenge.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this challenge from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @challenge.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :pointsSpend %><br>
    <%= f.number_field :pointsSpend %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :rules %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :rules %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>

</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to pass the class to the `form_for` method like this:

```
<%= form_for(@challenge, html: { class: 'form-inline' }) do |f| %>

  <% if @challenge.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@challenge.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this challenge from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @challenge.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :pointsSpend %><br>
    <%= f.number_field :pointsSpend %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :rules %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :rules %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>

</form>
```

Comment: Its still vertical. Perhaps its to do with the fact that the form is rendered within the div called challengeCentre. How can I make that div display horizontally?

Comment: what are the styles on `challengeCentre`? How are you rendering the form into that div?

Comment: there are no styles. It is rendered from an ajax call